# How can I make a foam without an immersion blender?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, blender, foam

I want to try some experiments with molecular gastronomy foams, but all the recipes I've seen involve using an immersion blender to create the foam. Can I use a whisk to make the foam? What about my Vita-mix? Are there any changes I would need to make to the process based on the change in methodology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vita mix should work pretty well; maybe you could carefully drag a spatula in the top of the vortex (nowhere near the blade!) to introduce more air. A whisk will be pretty slow going. And then there is a whole other category of foams made in a whipped cream canister. Here is a link to get you started: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9lJMGImGKE

Comment: Good idea with the whisk. Mine actually came with a muddler type thing that won't hit the blades that will probably work great.

Comment: I just thought of one more way that may work. The whole trick is to introduce air, so try using very little liquid in the vita mix, maybe just enough to half cover the blades. That will produce approximately the same scenario as people use with their immersion blender to make foam, where the blade is skimmed along the top of the liquid surface.

Answer (score 4):

A hand beater would work, or a stand mixer, using whisk attachments.